# Nested spin_lock_irqsave

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

If the code is as below

```
void test(void)
{
  spin_lock_irqsave(&lock1, flag);
  ...
  func1();
  ...
  spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock1, flag);
}

void func1(void)
{
  spin_lock_irqsave(&lock2, flag);
  ...
  spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock2, flag);
}
```

Will there be any issue with the code? when the `spin_unlock_irqrestore` is called in func1, will the interrupt be enabled already? What I want to achieve is `test()` routine can be executed without any interruption by scheduler or interrupts. Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually, that's the whole point of having `spin_lock_irqsave()/spin_unlock_irq_restore()` in addition to `spin_lock_irq()/spin_unlock_irq()`.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I've found in the documentation, and I haven't completely exhausted my search, the `flag` will save the state of the bits that set the different flags and then turn off interrupts, then restore it on end.  If interrupts have been turned off by the first call `test` and then you do another call, I would assume (and nothing indicates otherwise that I've found) that it would leave the interrupts turned off, store the `flags` and restore them inside `func()` and then restore them back to the state `flag` has in `test`.

Interrupts should only be re-enabled after your `test` function.

I would say your only catch is that you cannot use the same `flag` variable in both functions, else you'll overwrite the first one in your inner call and then reset it, and if any flags changed in between your calls, you may reset the outer one to the wrong state.

Comment: This is correct.  Nested spin_lock_irqsave() is perfectly fine, as long as you use different "flags" variables.